# How to answer this Matlab image processing homework?

Tags: matlab

I'm stuck here, I tried many times but unable to get my final answer.

[image]

Code:

```
I = imread('C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\pears.png');
H = fspecial('average', [3 3]);
J = imfilter(I, H);
figure, imshow(I);
figure, imshow(J);
```

Comment: Please show us your approach as code

Comment: I = imread('C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\pears.png');
H = fspecial('average', [3 3]);
J = imfilter(I, H);
figure, imshow(I);    After it I'm unable to write equation to intensify the image.
figure, imshow(J);

Comment: Add your code always into the question. This makes it easier to read and more likely to get an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind suggestions, Actually it was my 1st post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:
(Maybe you have to change the threshold);

```
threshold = 126;

image = imread('C:\Users\Ahsan\Desktop\pears.png');

%   Apply the filder
filterImage = conv2(image, ones(3)/9, 'same');

%   Check which pixels are equal or greater than the threshold
masked = filterImage >= threshold;

%   Replace all pixels of the filteredImage which are below the threshold
%   with the original pixels.
filterImage(~masked) = image(~masked);

%   Display result
figure(1);

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(image, []);

subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(filterImage, []);
```